# The expectation of restriced sampling.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, sampling

Suppose a red ball is selected with probability $p$, and a blue ball is selected with probability $q = 1 - p$ in each independent random draw. And one will stop sampling once he (or she) reaches his (or her) goal of $r$ red balls and $b$ blue balls, or once he (or she) has collected $m$ balls in total. Let $N_{r b m}$ be the number of samples drawn.

Now I want to know the expectation of $N_{r b m}$, i.e. $\mathrm{E} N_{r b m}$. Maybe a recurrence relation is enough.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably you have $m > r+b$ as otherwise the answer is $m$

Comment: @Henry. Thanks! But what the recurrence relation of $\mathrm{E} N_{rbm}$ when $r + b \leq m$?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can find an expression based on the binomial probability of reaching a position immediately before the last draw and then making a suitable final draw

This might produce something like this (unchecked): $$m-\sum_{k=r}^{m-d-1} m{m-1\choose k}p^kq^{m-k-1} \\+\sum_{j=r}^{m-d-1} (j+d){j+d-1\choose j}p^jq^{d}  + \sum_{i=d}^{m-r-1} (i+r){i+r-1\choose i}p^rq^{i}  $$

so if $m\le r+d$ then all the summations disappear and you just get $m$

Comment: Thanks so much!